# My thread closes while the program is running

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c++-cli

I'm programming a gmae in c++.net, it's like the space impact. I start the game form and on its load event I create a thread to play a music in the background of the application.

The problem is that when I press the space bar to shoot it also plays a sound, and it stops the main music.

I've already had this issue, but I was told that threads should fix the problem.

I've created the thread and my problem stands. Some help would be appreciated.

```
    private: System::Void GameForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{

    Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(PlayMusic));
    newThread->Name = "MusicaImperio";
    newThread->IsBackground = true;
    if(newThread->IsBackground == true)
    newThread->Start();
    //Sleep(3000);

}
```

This is the load event, and this is the Playmusic method:

```
    static void PlayMusic()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("../Musicas/Game.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
}
```

Comment: `PlaySound` is not fit for this; you can only play one sound at a time with it.

Comment: could you tell me another function for this kind of things?

Comment: I think you could use [DirectSound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416960(v=vs.85).aspx), and there are possibly other Windows APIs. Many people use libraries. (No, I don't know which one would be suitable for you.)

Answer (score 0):

if you try to not run it on the background.

Does it work then or still nothing ?

maybe you can see what happens